# using nonlocal or global inside a class body

Tags: python, class, scope, class-attributes, python-nonlocal

In python it is valid to use an `import` statement inside a class to define class variables that are just stolen from other modules:

```py
class CustomMath:
    from math import pi

assert isinstance(CustomMath.pi, float) # passes
```

It is also valid to refer to a global variable to the class with the very confusing statement `x=x`

```py
x = 1
class Test:
    # this loads the global variable x and stores in in the class scope
    x = x
assert Test.x == 1 # passes
```

However if I am using a function to generate classes is there a similar way to copy a variable from the function arguments to the class body?

I want something of this nature:

```py
def generate_meta_options(model, design):
    class Meta:
        # copy the nonlocal variable model to this scope
        # but this isn't valid syntax
        model = (nonlocal model)
        design = translate_old_design_spec_to_new_format((nonlocal design))
    return Meta
```

The parameter name matters because it is being passed by keyword not by order `generate_meta_options(design="A", model=Operation)` and the name in the class has to be the same, I have found a work around by making variable aliases to all of the inputs but this is kind of annoying

```py
def generate_meta_options_works(model, design):
    _model = model
    _design = design
    class Meta:
        model = _model
        design = translate_old_design_spec_to_new_format(_design)
    return Meta
```

Is there a better way of achieving this using the `nonlocal` keyword? It seems that python does allow `nonlocal` and `global` to be used in a class but the variables are not retained in the class so I can't imagine a use case for it.

```py
gl = 'this is defined globally'
def nonlocal_in_class_test():
    lo = 'this is defined locally'
    class Test:
        nonlocal lo
        global gl
        lo = 'foo'
        gl = 'bar'
    assert lo == 'foo' # passes
    assert gl == 'bar' # passes
    assert hasattr(Test, 'lo') or hasattr(Test, 'gl'), 'lo nor gl was put in the class scope' # fails
```

I'm sure the library I'm using just needs an object with attribute lookup so I could move away from classes but every example I've seen uses classes (I suspect because inheriting multiple configs is natural) so I am hesitant to go that route.

It seems really odd that it is easier to copy a variable from a different module than it is to copy one right in the above scope so I thought I'd ask, is there a way to copy a variable from a `nonlocal` scope into a class attribute without creating a separate variable with a distinct name?

As a tangent is there any case where using the `nonlocal` or `global` keywords inside a class body is useful? I assume it is not useful but there is also no reason to do extra work to disallow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nonlocal` wouldn't work in any event, because variables have only one scope in the case where `nonlocal` applies (function locals, which are subtly different from class definition scope); by trying to use `nonlocal`, you'd say `model` was *never* part of the class definition scope, just something from outside it.

I personally prefer your kinda hacky reassignment so `_model` outside the class and `model` inside the class don't conflict, but if you hate it, there is an option to directly access the class-in-progress's namespace, `vars()` (or `locals()`; the two are equivalent in this case, but I don't *think* of the class scope as being locals, even though they act a lot like it).

Because the scope is not *really* a function scope, you can in fact mutate it through the `dict` from `vars`/`locals`, allowing your desired result to look like:

```
def generate_meta_options(model, design):
    class Meta:
        vars().update(
            model=model,
            design=translate_old_design_spec_to_new_format(design)
        )
    return Meta
```

Using the keyword argument passing form of `dict.update` means the code even *looks* mostly like normal assignment. And Python won't complain if you then use those names earlier (seeing outer scope) or later (seeing newly defined names) in the class definition:

```
def generate_meta_options(model, design):
    print("Before class, in function:", model, design)  # Sees arguments
    class Meta:
        print("Inside class, before redefinition:", model, design)  # Sees arguments
        vars().update(
            model=model,
            design=design+1
        )
        print("Inside class, after redefinition:", model, design)  # Sees class attrs
    print("After class, in function:", model, design)  # Sees arguments
    return Meta

MyMeta = generate_meta_options('a', 1)
print(MyMeta.model, MyMeta.design)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZGxCoMwEIZ3n@JwUWkQpJvg0G4dfAZJzWkDepEkFnx6q4lIHSr9lyO5@7/8XIbJvhRd51lgAy0Sam6x6tHySg1WKjJxrwR2DAQa2VKSB7Bo0JJsHN6xURqh7rgxDCRBM1K9uvKQwdHnbG4QyoXuMV@oBxkpdtTTgzUusSTJE@SqN9cmTtJxEEv4eL9e5RyF9x0anlH4csn2XnIejDcW9T@5NvfNzf@9II121OQ2FATltFYofvxLxCMGWRL4l/xwujG304ae5w8)

Comment: Also, the import statement works because it basically assigns the value of an *attribute* to a local name, not the value of a non-local variable with the same name.

Comment: @chepner: Yeah, I got the impression the OP understood that, they just were using it as an example of something they knew how to do but couldn't figure out how to adapt to their similar use case (both of them are ultimately making a class attribute with name `X` from some existing name also named `X`, but only one of them having scope conflicts), which is why I didn't address it directly.

Comment: I mentioned it because the namespace-not-a-scope behavior of a `class` statement isn't really the issue. You can't initialize a local variable in a function from the value of a non-local variable with the same name, either.

Comment: @chepner I guess that is fair but using a different variable name is always an option if it is just nested functions, having both keyword arguments and class attribute names were necessary for this to be an issue at all. Also I guess `var = globals()["var"]` would work for globals if that was ever needed.

Comment: Using a different variable is absolutely the right solution. You have complete control over the local variable names while writing the functions.

Comment: I'm so glad I asked because using `vars` to update namespace is really neat, although I assume it isn't guaranteed to be portable to other python implementations so I will stick to the aliasing scheme. (I don't hate it that much) Thanks for answering! :)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: `vars()` is portable in a class (or at global scope). The nature of [the language definition for name lookups](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) along with [the spec for class definitions requiring it to use a `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) combine to require modifications of `vars()` to work in a class, and necessitate flexible lookup that will behave as shown, producing the class attribute if defined at lookup time, and the outer scope's variable of the same name if not.

Comment: But yeah, the aliasing scheme is less ugly to me (even when `vars()` is legal, doing this feels ugly). Only other solution I can come up with would be using a metaclass (not one that actually stayed on as the metaclass, just something to inject the class `dict` with the keyword arguments passed) that allowed you to do `class Meta(metaclass=NameInjector, model=model, design=translate_old_design_spec_to_new_format(design)):`, or roughly equivalently, a class decorator that injected the stuff after everything else was defined. But that's even worse than the other two solutions. :-)